# Deserializing Text File Data in C (Linked List)

Tags: c, file, linked-list, nodes, file-handling

I want to make the text file data human readable. So far, I have managed to serialize the code but I am having trouble to deserialize the code from the text file and print the data on the screen.

```
struct Node{
    struct Node *next;
    int c;
    int d;
};

struct Node *head=NULL;
struct Node *current=NULL;
void display(){
    struct Node *temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("\nData : %d", temp->c);
        printf("\nData : %d", temp->d);
        temp=temp->next;
    }

}
//Problem here 
struct Node* deserialize(char* data, struct Node *p){
    sscanf(data,"%d %d", &p->c, &p->d );
    return p;
 }

char* serialize(const struct Node *p){
    char* ser = malloc(100*sizeof(*ser));
    if(!ser){
        printf("\nUnable to allocate memory");
    }else{
        sprintf(ser, "%d %d",p->c, p->d);

    }
    return ser;
}
// and here
void readFromFile(){
    char *d =malloc(100*sizeof(*d)); 
    FILE *fp =  fopen("read.txt", "r");
    struct Node *f;
    for(f= head; f!=NULL; f=f->next){
       fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]%*c", d);
      // printf("\nString : %s",d);
         deserialize(d, f); 
    printf("\n%d %d", f->c, f->d);

}
fclose(fp);
}

void createNode(){
    struct Node *temp = NULL;
    temp = (struct Node* )malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if(temp == NULL){
        printf("\n\t\tMemory for the new record cannot be allocated!!!");
        return;
     }
     printf("\nEnter number");
     scanf("%d",&temp->c);
     printf("\nEnter number");
     scanf("%d",&temp->d);
     temp->next = NULL;
        if(head==NULL){
        head = current = temp;
    }else{
        current->next = temp;
        current = temp;
    }
     printf("Record Inserted");
        char* data = serialize(temp);
        FILE *fp =  fopen("reads.txt", "a");
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n",data);
        fclose(fp);
        free(data);

}
int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        createNode();
    }
    display();
    readFromFile();

}
```

I am having trouble with fscanf and sscanf part. How can I get it right?

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "%s", d);` : `d` isn't initialized. There is a need to allocate a memory block. Also `%s` no spaces.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I allocated the block but I'm still unable to get the data from the file.

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "%s", d);` --> `fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]%*c", d);`

Comment: Can you post the output which you are getting? Print "d" obtained after fscanf.

Comment: @Jay It's printing nothing when `readFromFile()` is invoked, screen is crashing.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I changed the line too, but still nothing is there, except for the crashed screen.

Comment: @Kamal, Comment the last printf in readFromFile() and add a printf to print "d" there

Comment: `FILE *fp =  fopen("read.txt", "r");` --> `FILE *fp =  fopen("reads.txt", "r");`, `sscanf(data,"%d %d", p->c, p->d );` --> `sscanf(data,"%d %d", &p->c, &p->d );`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY finally, there is something.  But output is not as expected.

I am giving input 

`2 3`
`4 5`
`6 7`

Reading from file is 

`256973 3`
`256973 5`
`256973 7`

Comment: Do the contents of the files are deleted every time you test?

Comment: No, rather they are appended.

Comment: Probably, Typo in your actual code there are still.

Comment: I have update the code snippet here.

Comment: `FILE *fp =  fopen("read.txt", "r");` I already pointed out.

Comment: Oh, that's blunder on my part. Thank you very much I got through it. I wish just one more modification for this code. It reads only first 3 records because I am taking 3 nodes data each time. It should display all of the nodes present in the file.

Comment: There is a need to create a list by the read data from the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Node* deserialize(char* data, struct Node *p){
    sscanf(data,"%d %d", p->c, p->d );
    return p;
 }
```

should be

```
struct Node* deserialize(char* data, struct Node *p){
    sscanf(data,"%d %d", &(p->c), &(p->d) );
    return p;
 }
```

Comment: yeah, it solved the crashing problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct Node{
    struct Node *next;
    int c;
    int d;
};

struct Node *head=NULL;
struct Node *current=NULL;

struct Node* newNode(int c,int d){

    struct Node*  nd;
    nd=malloc(sizeof(*nd));
    nd->c=c;
    nd->d=d;
    nd->next=NULL;
    return nd;
}

struct Node* AppendNode(struct Node*parent,struct Node* nd){
    if(parent)
        parent->next=nd;
    return nd;
}


void display(){
    struct Node *temp=head;
    while(temp){
        printf("Data : %d, %d\n", temp->c, temp->d);
        temp=temp->next;
    }

}
//Problem here 
struct Node* deserialize(char* data, struct Node *p){
    sscanf(data,"%d %d", &p->c, &p->d );
    return p;
 }

char* serialize(const struct Node *p){
    static char ser[100];
    sprintf(ser, "%d %d",p->c, p->d);
    return ser;
}
// and here


void readFromFile(const char *filename){
    struct Node     *f=NULL;
    int             c,d;

    FILE *fp =  fopen(filename, "r");

    while(fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &c,&d)==2){

        f=AppendNode(f,newNode(c,d));
        if(!f){
            perror("readFromFile::AppendNode()\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        if(!head)
            head=f;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return ;

}

void createNode(const char *filename){

    struct Node *temp=newNode(0,0);

    if(!temp){
        perror("createNode::newNode()\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf(" %d",    &temp->c);

    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf(" %d",    &temp->d);


    current=AppendNode(current,temp);
    if(!head) head=current;

    printf("Record Inserted\n\n");


    FILE *fp =  fopen(filename, "a");
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n",serialize(temp));
    fclose(fp);

}

void DeleteNodes(){

    while(head){
        current=head;
        head=head->next;
        free(current);
    }
}

#define DATA_FILE   "read.txt"
int main(){

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        createNode(DATA_FILE );
    }
    printf("printing entries: \n");
    display();
    DeleteNodes();

    printf("\nreading from file: \n");
    readFromFile(DATA_FILE );
    display();
    DeleteNodes();

    printf("\nDONE: \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should add some explaination

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  thanks, i updated the code.